# Free (or great) VST panner with haas effect

Tags: mixing, vst, stereo, panning

Do any of you know about a nice and simple stereo panning VST that also does haas (delay-based) panning? Preferably free, but if you have a good recommendation, then let it spill anyway..

I'm just looking for two simple pots; one for traditional (volume-based) pan, and one for haas pan in either direction -- but it would actually have been nice as a part of the daw or a channel strip VST as well. What i'm really looking for is quick access to stereo experimentation. Maybe there are other types of psychoacoustic plugins worth mentioning as well?

I'm mostly using Cubase for now, but I might try switching to Pro Tools or Logic.

Comment: What DAW are you using? It is pretty easy to set something like this up in Ableton using racks and one of the included delays. Alternately, it is easy to build a haas panner in something like PureData or Max/MSP. I suspect it is also easy in Logic's environment, if you can grok that :)

Comment: @ObscureRobot Mostly Cubase for now. PD and Max look interesting, I hope to try them some time. Why do you think it would be easy in Logic (never used it)?

Comment: Logic has a thing called the Environment which is a sort of awkward modular system for MIDI processing. If you already understand it well, it may be easy to use it to create a haas panner with the built in delay units. If not, then it will probably be a nightmare.

Answer (score 5):

You can do a basic implementation manually in any daw:

1. Copy the track
2. Pan both tracks left and right respectively and symmetrically
3. The dry channel should be around 18dB louder than the Haas channel
4. Add a time delay of 13ms-~50ms to 'Haas' channel'

**Be careful how much Haas you use**, it affects the tonality of the track when summed to mono.

If you have Reaktor, I think I still have an ensemble, which handled this nicely when I had Sonar and no plugin to do it without copying tracks.

Comment: This is a good starting point for creating the Haas effect in your DAW of choice. If the DAW supports sending audio to arbitrary audio processing tracks or channels then you could do that rather than making a copy of the track. This is particularly beneficial if you are working with a CPU-heavy plugin or making use of stochastic elements in your synth or processing.

Answer (score 2):

There is  [Freehaas](http://www.vescofx.com/vfxFreeHaas).

I'm not sure how successful it is in implementing the haas effect, buit provides thickness to my mixes when I use it, and it's intuitive and light.

Answer (score 1):

Reaper has this as a native (and very usable) effect plugin. It's not one of [the plugins they offer as gratis VSTs](http://www.reaper.fm/reaplugs/index.php), but if you're considering to switch the DAW anyway do [give Reaper a try](http://www.reaper.fm/download.php), it's great and not quite GPL but about as free as proprietary software can get!

As said by ObscureRobot, this kind of effect is really easy to write yourself, I built one a couple of years ago in SynthMaker. The UI is a bit different from what you asked for, but it should work fine for what you want.